# Azure Cognitive Services Speech on Blazor-- C# / JS? extremely confused

Tags: javascript, azure, blazor, azure-cognitive-services

I'm running a Blazor site, and I've read that for Microsoft Cognitive Services TTS, I need to use the Javascript SDK.

Okay, so I get to the following JS samples page, with two folders: one for "node.js" and one for "browser", which I interpret to mean "not requiring node.js"

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples/js/browser

**Prerequisites**

- A subscription key for the Speech service. See Try the speech service for free.
- A **PC or Mac, with a working speaker.**
- A text editor.
- **Ensure you have Node.js installed.**

**Okay. . . so is it or is it ain't possible to use this framework in vanilla Javascript?**

Comment: In the documentation you linked, those are the prerequisites for the _sample_.  If you want to run the sample code, using that repo, it needs node.  

Also in the documentation, there's an intro to using the [Speech SDK for Javascript][1].

I don't know what you mean by "vanilla Javascript" as that usually means "without any frameworks" like jQuery or so on. Node is used for dev tools like Webpack, so maybe? Maybe not?

  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speech-to-text?tabs=macos%2Cterminal&pivots=programming-language-javascript

Comment: Yes, I meant "Not using node.js" as there are two sample folders in the repo: "node.js" and "browser," which I interpreted to mean "Not using any framework outside HTML/vanilla JS."   The link you gives is for speech-to-text, not text-to-speech.

Comment: BTW-- I feel, Blazor being Microsoft's flagship Web framework, that there should be a page somewhere showing how to use every Microsoft technology under the sun with it.  It's pretty sad when I can find better answers with chat-GTP than with MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

You can download and open both the [speech-to-text sample page](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/js/browser/index.html) and the [text-to-speech sample page](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/js/browser/synthesis.html) in your browser without any node.js. The node requirement refers to running the full sample, which demonstrates a server/client auth token retrieval pattern commonly requested by customers.

Comment: Interesting.  I was able to use the .net library to retrieve a token (or it looked like one, I haven't actually tried the js code yet).